# Need assistance incorporating multiple variables in a foreach against this script

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and trying to modify an existing script to run multiple variables (domains) in a foreach loop.  Snip of script below.

$DomainIdentities is the variable that will determine the $TargetDomain the script is running against.  Let's say I have a couple domains, domainA.lab.local and domainB.lab.local, what's the best way to loop these two in a foreach to run against both domains?

```
    Write-Host 'Gathering and analyzing target domain information...'
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    Import-Module GroupPolicy

    $TargetDomain = Get-AdDomain -Identity $DomainIdentities | Select Name,DNSRoot,NetBIOSName,DomainMode,PDCEmulator

    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host '   Domain NetBIOS name: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.NetBIOSName
    Write-Host '   Domain DNS name: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.DNSRoot 
    Write-Host '   PDC emulator: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.PDCEmulator
    Write-Host '   DomainMode: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.DomainMode
    Write-Host '   Checking domain functional mode is ''Windows2008Domain'' or higher.....' -NoNewline

    $Status | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'DomainModePassed' -Value (!(($TargetDomain.DomainMode -eq 'Windows2000Domain') -or ($TargetDomain.DomainMode -eq 'Windows2003InterimDomain') -or ($TargetDomain.DomainMode -eq 'Windows2003Domain')))
    If ($Status.DomainModePassed) {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'PASSED'} 
    Else {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'FAILED'}

    Write-Host ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `Domains` as a parameter that takes multiple string values at the top of your script:

```
param(
    [string[]]$Domains
)

Write-Host 'Gathering and analyzing target domain information...'
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module GroupPolicy

foreach($Domain in $Domains){
    $TargetDomain = Get-ADDomain -Identity $Domain | Select Name,DNSRoot,NetBIOSName,DomainMode,PDCEmulator

    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host '   Domain NetBIOS name: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.NetBIOSName
    Write-Host '   Domain DNS name: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.DNSRoot 
    Write-Host '   PDC emulator: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.PDCEmulator
    Write-Host '   DomainMode: ' -NoNewline; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $TargetDomain.DomainMode
    Write-Host '   Checking domain functional mode is ''Windows2008Domain'' or higher.....' -NoNewline

    $Status | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'DomainModePassed' -Value (!(($TargetDomain.DomainMode -eq 'Windows2000Domain') -or ($TargetDomain.DomainMode -eq 'Windows2003InterimDomain') -or ($TargetDomain.DomainMode -eq 'Windows2003Domain')))
    If ($Status.DomainModePassed) {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'PASSED'} 
    Else {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'FAILED'}

    Write-Host ''
}
```

Then pass the domain names to the script like so:

```
.\path\to\script.ps1 -Domains ad.contoso.com,ad.fabrikam.com
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, was able to incorporate a ValdidateSet with all of our domains.